# What is Sublime Text 2’s equivalent to vim’s Ctrl+P?

Tags: vim, text-editors, sublime-text-2

Sublime Text is great, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) in vim (inserting a word with same starting characters in insert mode) is such an essential feature that I just cannot live without it. Is this functionality available in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 1):

It should popup by default as you type, but if it doesn't, you can press `<Ctrl-Space>` to force it open.

Comment: Great it works. Thanks a lot. BTW, can I choose the candidate words using some key shortcuts other than up and down keys?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but if you keep typing, the list should get refined as you type.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the simple <kbd>TAB</kbd> does the job. Say if you already have written `Triangulation`, then after writing `Tri` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will get auto-completed. There is no popup like it is when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>. The behavior is the same as in vim except it's even more intuitive and convinient than vim's way of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>. I am amazed by Sublime Text, again.

Comment: Interesting. This seems a bit odd to me, since I typically expect `tab` to insert a tab unconditionally. Of course, if you like this behavior, Vim (or at least the Vim community) will provide... http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=182